# How to find the probability that candidate $A$ wins

Tags: probability, statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ro8re.png)

In an election between two candidates, $A$ and $B$, one million individuals cast their votes. Among these, 2000 know candidate $A$ from her election campaign and vote unanimously for her. The remaining 998000 voters are undecided and make their decision independently of each other by flipping a fair coin. Approximate the probability $p_A$ that candidate $A$ wins up to 3 significant figures.

Comment: Do you have any thoughts yourself?

Comment: do it need a binomial model

Comment: @yyyyy: You could do it that way, but it sounds tedious (without computer aid).  I suspect you're supposed to use the normal approximation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $0.977$!

The amount of votes candidate $A$ needs to win is $500001$. Since candidate $A$ already has $2000$ guaranteed votes, candidate $A$ needs $498001$ votes to win. To find this, we simply do $$1-\text{binomcdf}(998000,0.5,498001) \approx 0.977$$

Comment: Good idea to show exact binomial computation using software (+1), but can you say what software?

Comment: @BruceET The TI-84 plus CE I have handled it very well, and then to check my answers I redid the calculation in mathematica. I got the same result for both.

Answer (score 1):

**Outline:** A normal approximation would use $\mu = np$ and $\sigma = \ \sqrt{np(1-p)},$
where $n = 998000$ and $p = 1/2.$ If $X \sim \mathsf{NORM}(\mu, \sigma),$
then you seek $P(X \ge 49801),$ which you can evaluate by standardizing
and using printed normal tables:

$$P(X > 498001) =P\left(\frac{X - \mu}{\sigma} > \frac{498001 - \mu}{\sigma}\right) = P(Z > z) \approx 0.977,$$
where the numerical value of $z$ is found by plugging in the values of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ from above. [I have omitted the continuity correction because
of the size of the numbers.]

If you use R statistical software, you can get the answer $0.977$ (correct to three places)
either using an exact binomial computation or an approximate normal one.

```
 1 - pbinom(498001, 998000, .5)
 ## 0.9771959
 1 - pnorm(498001, 499000, 499.4)
 ## 0.9772715
```

I'm not sure which statistical calculators ccould handle such large numbers
without error messages or errors.

*Note:* Often normal approximations are only accurate to about two places--even
when $n$ and $p$ obey various 'rules of thumb' for 'permitted' use of normal
to approximate binomial probabilities.

This problem has two advantages toward a better approximation: (a) $n$ is
very large and (b) $p = 1/2,$ making the binomial precisely symmetrical.
Therefore, you get about four places of accuracy, where you are only asked for three.